# How to Join two table and display the data to table in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i creating a simple car retail system in asp.netmvc.i want to join two table and display the data to table in Asp.net MVC. i don't know how to join and display the data into the table.what i tried so far i attached below.

**car model**

```
 public partial class carreg
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string carno { get; set; }
        public string make { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string Available { get; set; }
    }
```

**rentail model**

```
public partial class rentail
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string carno { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> custid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> sdate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> edate { get; set; }

        public virtual rentail rentail1 { get; set; }

}
```

car

```
id  carno   make    model   Available
1   A0001   honda   viff    yes
2   A0002   Honda   uii     no
```

**rentail**

```
  id  carno   custid     fee      sdate       edate
   3    A0001    1      3434      2019-12-09  2019-12-27
   4    A0002    1      12000     2019-11-01  2019-11-29
```

i want to view the data look like this below

```
   id    carno  custid   fee      sdate       edate       Available  
   3   A0001     1      3434      2019-12-09  2019-12-27    yes
   4   A0002     1      12000     2019-11-01  2019-11-29    no
```

**RentController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.rentails.ToList());
        }
```

pass in to view

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication36.Models.rentail>

  <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Carno
                </th>
                <th>
                    Custid
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fee
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start date
                </th>
                <th>
                    End date
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.carno
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.custid
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.fee
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.sdate
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @item.edate
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

In this table i want add another colum available how to join can table and retail to get the data

Comment: rentails  data displayed successfully. but i don't the join

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not a data access library. It doesn't query databases. Are you using Entity Framework? Which version? In **all** ORMs, it's the ORM's job to generate joins from the relations between entities. If you have to write a JOIN, the entities weren't configured correctly.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? 5? 6? 6.2? EF Core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You should create one class ViewModel: contain any property you want.
Example:

```
public class RentailViewModel
{
    public int RentalId { get; set; }

     public string carno { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> custid { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> fee { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> sdate { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> edate { get; set; }

     public string Available { get; set; }

    // The rest of properties
}
```

Secondly, `Rencontroller`, you can get like the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = (from r in db.rentails
                  join c in db.cars on r.carno equals c.carno
                  select new RentailViewModel
                  {
                      RentalId = r.RentalId,
                      carno = r.carno,
                      Available = c.Available,

                      // The rest of properties here
                  }).ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

Comment: custid = r.custid,
                              fee = r.fee,
                              sdate = r.sdate,
                              edate = r.edate,      these  properties getting error of 
cannot implicity convert type int? to int And explicit conversion exists

Comment: I comment "// The rest of properties", Please update the rest of your properties in RentailViewModel

Comment: RentailViewModel  model i updated but custid = r.custid, fee = r.fee, sdate = r.sdate, edate = r.edate, these properties getting error of cannot implicity convert type int? to int And explicit conversion exists

Comment: Becuz your Retail Model has nullable prop (public Nullable<int> custid { get; set; }), So pls update code like this one.

Comment: public int custid { get; set; }

        public int fee { get; set; }
        public DateTime sdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime edate { get; set; }

        public string Available { get; set; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203965/discussion-between-phong-nguyen-and-java-fiver).

Comment: now i will able to write sir thanks. but in view page  @item.avaliable is not there on the properies sir

Comment: 2013 version sir

Comment: @Javafiver not really - there's no reason to use joins with ORMs. The ORM generates the joins from the relations between objects. If you have to use joins, there's a problem. `Rental` should have a `Car` property

Comment: Pls update namespace as well,
Now it's @model IEnumerable<WebApplication36.Models.rentail>